# Entity Framework 6 Issue with mapping foreign keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 3 entities: **Question**

```
public enum QuestionType
{
    Scenario,
    Step
}

public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [Required] [MaxLength(255)] public string Text { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(255)] public string FrameText { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public QuestionType Type { get; set; }

    public DefaultAnswer DefaultAnswer { get; set; }
    public IList<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

**Answer**

```
public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    [Required] [MaxLength(255)] public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }

    public Scenario Scenario { get; set; }
    public IList<Formula> Formulas { get; set; }
    public IList<Image> Images { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, **DefaultAnswer**:

```
public class DefaultAnswer
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }

    public Answer Answer { get; set; }
    public Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

The relationships between **Question** and **Answer** is obvious. I want to set a **DefaultAnswer** for a question, so I have added a navigation property `DefaultAnswer` to the **Question** model.
This is optional, because it can be blank.

So, I have tried to create the relationship like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DefaultAnswer>().HasKey(m => new { m.QuestionId, m.AnswerId });
modelBuilder.Entity<Question>().HasOptional(m => m.DefaultAnswer).WithRequired(m => m.Question);
modelBuilder.Entity<DefaultAnswer>().HasRequired(m => m.Answer).WithMany().HasForeignKey(m => m.AnswerId);
```

But this doesn't work, it creates another field called `Question_Id` in the **DefaultAnswers** table.....
This is what EF generates:

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.DefaultAnswers",
        c => new
            {
                QuestionId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                AnswerId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                Question_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.QuestionId, t.AnswerId })
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Answers", t => t.AnswerId, cascadeDelete: true)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Questions", t => t.Question_Id)
        .Index(t => t.AnswerId)
        .Index(t => t.Question_Id);

}
```

which is not what I want.
I actually want this:

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.DefaultAnswers",
        c => new
            {
                QuestionId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                AnswerId = c.Int(nullable: false),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.QuestionId, t.AnswerId })
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Answers", t => t.AnswerId, cascadeDelete: true)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Questions", t => t.QuestionId)
        .Index(t => t.AnswerId)
        .Index(t => t.QuestionId);

}
```

Does anyone know how I can create that relationship while still keeping the navigation property in **Question**?

Comment: Would it be better to just add `IsDefault` property to the Answer entity ?

Comment: Have you tried `.HasForeignKey(m => m.QuestionId)` ?

Comment: Within the context of the OP, I think koryakinp's comment for an isDefault property on the Answer entity is the cleanest and easiest solution.  No additional extra work with modelbuilder, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the comment suggesting simply flagging an answer as 'default' sounds a good one, but to attempt to help with the actual question....

OK, an edit which I *think* gives you what you want....

so, models I've used here:

```
public enum QuestionType
{
    Scenario,
    Step
}

public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [Required] [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string FrameText { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public QuestionType Type { get; set; }

    public DefaultAnswer DefaultAnswer { get; set; }
    public IList<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }

    public Scenario Scenario { get; set; }
    public Question Question { get; set; }

    //commented these out for the sake of this
    //example
   /*public IList<Formula> Formulas { get; set; }
    public IList<Image> Images { get; set; }*/
}

public class DefaultAnswer
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }

    public Answer Answer { get; set; }
    public Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

Relationships defined thusly:

```
//don't need a compound key for answers... 
//easier to just let each answer be entirely unique.            
modelBuilder.Entity<Answer>().HasKey(m => m.Id );

modelBuilder.Entity<Answer>().HasRequired(m => m.Question)
    .WithMany(q => q.Answers).HasForeignKey(m => m.QuestionId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Question>()
    .HasOptional(m => m.DefaultAnswer)
    .WithOptionalDependent(m => m.Question);

//default answer is basically a mapping table between questions and answers.
//so it has a compound key.  In fact the table should consist of ONLY these two key
//fields...
modelBuilder.Entity<DefaultAnswer>()
    .HasKey(m => new { m.AnswerId, m.QuestionId });
```

This produces this for me:

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.DefaultAnswers",
            c => new
                {
                    AnswerId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    QuestionId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.AnswerId, t.QuestionId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Answers", t => t.AnswerId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.AnswerId);
```

only thing I can't quite get my head around is how the cascade delete behaviour is set up...  slightly concerned that deleting a 'DefaultAnswer' record will delete the Answer - too late in the day for my brain to work this out I'm afraid!

Comment: I don't like using data annotations or properties that I will not use. Can this be done like this: `modelBuilder.Entity<Question>().HasOptional(m => m.DefaultAnswer).WithRequired().Map(m => m.MapKey("DefaultAnswerId"));`

Comment: It's actually quite useful to have the Id available I find - though mostly for when populating data.  I'll have a little play with it...

Comment: Incidentally, why not annotations?  Makes it nice and clear right there in the model, and lets EF deal with how to link everything...

Comment: I hate them :) you have to look into each class to see the relationship, much easier when it is in one place

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the intent behind introducing the DefaultAnswer entity.  But this sort of relationship can be modeled without it.  EG:

```
public enum QuestionType
{
    Scenario,
    Step
}

public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [Required] [MaxLength(255)] public string Text { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(255)] public string FrameText { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public QuestionType Type { get; set; }

    public int? DefaultAnswerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id,DefaultAnswerId")]
    public Answer DefaultAnswer { get; set; }
    public IList<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    [Required] [MaxLength(255)] public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }

    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }

    //public Scenario Scenario { get; set; }
    //public IList<Formula> Formulas { get; set; }
    //public IList<Image> Images { get; set; }
}
class Db: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Question> Question { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Answer> Answer { get; set; }



    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Answer>().HasKey(m => new { m.QuestionId, m.Id });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Answer>().HasRequired(m => m.Question).WithMany(q => q.Answers).HasForeignKey( m => m.QuestionId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Question>().HasOptional(m => m.DefaultAnswer);


    }


}
```

Comment: Can you show me how to do this without using DataAnnotations and doesn't your relationship state that DefaultAnswer is required? I need it to be optional, i.e. if no default is set there are no issues